# How to set up cgi-bin properly in apache2?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, cgi

I just set up a fresh apache2 with these Options for CGI:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
  AllowOverride None
  Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  AddHandler cgi-script cgi pl 
</Directory>
```

I created the directory at /var/www/cgi-bin, added the scripts, made them executable, restarted the server, but it still says gives a 404 when trying to access the scripts.

Any ideas?

(Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

Comment: Are the scripts executable by apache (should be userid `www-data`)?

Comment: Yes, I also tried changing the cgi-bin directory to `/usr/lib/cgi-bin` which is standard in ubuntu.
No change...

Comment: So how are you trying to access the scripts and what virtual host is the directive defined in?

Comment: Its in the `VirtualHost *:80` directive and I'm trying to access via the browser

Comment: We kinda guessed you were using a browser :). The question is are they served by an HTML file? How? What are the scripts? Perl? Python? PHP? Do other webpages also give 404 or only scripts?